# How to install crossroad of MSYS2?

Tags: linux, pip, msys2

I have been trying to install crossroad on MSYS2 through pip by typing `pip install crossroad` but couldn't install. Please help to install crossroad on MSYS2.

Comment: Hi wellcome to stackoverflow
You need to add a litle bit more info, like whats the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it on my PC and indeed it didn't download the `crossroad` 
If you look at the logs you see that it requires `python3-docutils` or `python2-docutils` which is a system package and not python package.
So i used debian/ubuntu so running

```
apt install python3-docutils
```

And then running `pip install crossroad` did install `crossroad` package.